# Noto CJK font issue with LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex

I am seeing the following error at the very end of first pass when I am trying to build my document:

```
</usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc(NotoSansCJKtc-Regular:3)

!LuaTeX error (file /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc): sfnt: table not found...
```

This is Ubuntu Xenial. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

I have noticed some questions related to Noto fonts and XeLaTeX. However, I am using LuaLaTeX so I have opened this new question.

**UPDATE**

The version is this:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (rev 5238)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc` has a `.ttc` extension, this is actually an Open Type Collection format font as Google says [here](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/). Support for OTC format was added to LuaTeX in LuaTeX beta-0.81.0 (please refer to [Revision 5330](https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=luatex&revision=5330)). So, if you are using older version of LuaTeX (e.g. Version beta-0.80.0, which is in TeX Live 2015), you cannot use OTC fonts with LuaTeX.

Let's consider the following file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{NotoSansCJK-Regular}
\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

If I compile this file with LuaTeX Version beta-0.80.0, LuaLaTeX gives an error.

```
$ lualatex test.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
# many logs here
!LuaTeX error (file ./NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc): sfnt: table not found...
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

If I compile with LuaTeX Version 0.95.0, it works well.

```
$ lualatex test.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)
 restricted system commands enabled.
# many logs here
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 3558 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log
```

This is the output (sorry for the Japanese Acrobat Reader).

[image: OTC-embedded PDF with LuaTeX]

Comment: btw, I wonder why the "beta-" prefix of LuaTeX version is omitted in TeX Live 2016. I think it's still in beta status...

Comment: No, it's "preview" i.e. prelude of 1.0 . This means that, as far as we can see, no more fundamental features will be added --- of course bugs will be fixed as usual.

Comment: @LuigiScarso Where is the "preview" version stated? [LuaTeX repository](https://foundry.supelec.fr/projects/luatex/) says that its development status is beta.

Comment: In the manual (it's called "pre-release" but we are not too format here). I will fix the repo page, thank you for the report.